# SSH client no longer finds private key in IdentityFile declaration

Tags: permissions, ssh

I'm getting this error when running `ssh myhost2`:

```
no such identity: /home/myusername/.ssh/myhost2_rsa: No such file or directory
```

## The details

On Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, I recently configured my SSH client to connect to multiple servers using different private keys.

My `~/.ssh/config` file has multiple host declarations, each with a different IdentityFile as below:

```
Host myhost1
        HostName myhost1.com
        user myhost1user
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myhost1_rsa

Host myhost2
        HostName myhost2.com
        user myhost2user
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myhost2_rsa

Host myhost3
        HostName myhost3.com

Host myhost4
        HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
        user myhost4user
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myhost4_rsa
```

When I set these up a few days ago, all were working properly. In other words, I could use a command like this:

```
ssh myhost2
```

...and the SSH connection would work as expected.

Today, using the same command results in this error:

```
no such identity: /home/myusername/.ssh/myhost2_rsa: No such file or directory
```

Convinced that this was a file permissions problem, I have checked and rechecked that there are no group permissions on my home folder nor on my .ssh folder.

- My ~/.ssh folder has 700 permissions
- My /home/myusername folder has 700 permissions

And I've checked and rechecked the private key files:

- Each of my private key files (*e.g.* `myhost2_rsa`) has 600 permissions
- Each of my private key files is owned by my user account (thanks for asking about this, @steeldriver). Here's the output of `namei -l /home/myusername/.ssh/myhost2_rsa`:

`f: /home/myusername/.ssh/myhost2_rsa
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  home
drwx------ myusername myusername myusername
drwx------ myusername myusername .ssh
-rw------- myusername myusername myhost2_rsa`

Since these were working a few days ago, I'm stupefied. This is still a recent Ubuntu setup for me, so I've been adding software and making configuration tweaks, but I can't think of anything that would have affected SSH or my home folder permissions.

Furthermore, I can still SSH into these same hosts from my Win7 machine via Putty using the same private keys.

Any ideas about what else I should be checking?

Comment: Did you verify the files' *ownership* as well as their permissions? what is the output of `namei -l /home/myusername/.ssh/myhost2_rsa`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. I did verify ownership, which I think is correct. Here's the output of `namei -l /home/myusername/.ssh/myhost2_rsa`

Comment: Sorry @steeldriver - My comment markdown chops here are sorely lacking. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/BkNccJeH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Permissions on ~/.ssh/config must also be set to 600.**

Once I set these permissions with `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`, the usual behavior began to work again (*e.g.* running command `ssh myhost4` resulted in a successful SSH connection to the server without an error).

Comment: It _might be_ that `ssh -vvv myhost4` would have told about the wrong permissions, but I'm not sure. You can revert the permissions and try.

Comment: I scoured that output, @PerlDuck. Didn't see it in there. But reverting the permissions and trying again might be worthwhile. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Interesting. When I do `chmod 666 ~/.ssh/config` then a simple `ssh myhost` fails with `Bad owner or permissions on /home/pduck/.ssh/config`. After `chmod 660` or `chmod 600` it works. `ssh -V` returns `OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`. Perhaps that makes a difference. I'm on 17.10.